# JavaScript Regex Remove Specific Consecutive Duplicate Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a regex function that will remove any non alpha numeric characters and remove all duplicate characters e.g. this : **aabcd*def%gGGhhhijkklmnoP\1223** would become this : **abcddefgGhijklmnoPR3**. I am able to remove the special characters easily but can't for the life of me work out how to remove the duplicate characters ? This is my current code for removing the special characters :

```
var oldString = aabcd*def%gGGhhhijkklmnoP\122
var filtered = oldStringt.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "");
```

How can I extend the above regex to check for duplicate characters and those duplicate characters separated by non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The regex is `/[^\w\s]|(.)\1/gi`

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cte94/

it uses the backreference to search for any character `(.)` followed by the same character `\1`

Unless by "check for duplicate characters" you meant that `aaa => a`

Then it's `/[^\w\s]|(.)(?=\1)/gi`

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cte94/1/

Be aware that both regexes don't distinguish between case. `A == a`, so `Aa` is a repetition. If you don't want it, take away the `i` from `/gi`

Comment: thank you so much is there anyway i can ensure that duplicates are removed that are separated by non-alphanumeric
characters.

Comment: @jonathanp Make it two Regexes (one to remove non-alphanumeric and one to remove duplicated). It's useless to make uber-complex Regexes, especially if you then have to handle/modify them

Comment: @jonathanp var filtered = oldString.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, "").replace(/(.)(?=\1)/gi, "");

Comment: @Pascalius Yep. Because the question didn't require it. The question explicitly used `\w`, that is `a-zA-Z0-9`.

Comment: @xanatos you are right, alpha numeric was requested. if someone needs it, this is the utf-version:  [^[\w]\s]|(.)(?=\1)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! What if you want to filter all duplicate letters but you want to authorize 2 consecutive letters? Can be useful because lot of right words has 2 same letters consecutive.

Comment: @Faks You should post a new question with some examples of what you want

Comment: @xanatos : Because my question would be really really close too this one I thought it was better to not create a similar/duplicate question.

Comment: @Faks `/[^\w\s]|(.)(?=\1\1)/gi` will remove only if there are at least three `aaa`, and will leave `aa` alone

Comment: @xanatos : Works perfectly! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

\1+ is the key

```
"aabcdd".replace(/(\w)\1+/g, function (str, match) {
    return match[0]
}); // abcd
```

Answer (score 2):

Non regex version:

```
var oldString = "aabcd*def%gGGhhhijkklmnoP\122";
var newString = "";

var len = oldString.length;
var c = oldString[0];
for ( var i = 1; i < len; ++i ) {
  if ( c != oldString[i] ) {
    newString += c;
  }
  c = oldString[i];
}
```

Comment: Hi that does a great job of removing the duplicated characters so would you suggest runing my regex first then executing the above ?

Answer (score 1):

short and simple input=Brahmananda output:Brahmnd
ref:http://jsfiddle.net/p7yu8etz/5/

```js
var str = "Brahmananda";
var reg = /(.)(.*?)(\1)/g;
while (reg.test(str))
str = str.replace(reg, "$1$2");
$("div").text(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><div>
```