# PHP regex to replace double or more characters with single character

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, double

Why the following won't work?

```
<?php
 $text = 'Hell   looo   w  orlldddddd!!!!!!!!!';
 $sanitized = preg_replace("/(\w|\s)\1{1,}/mi","$1",$text);
 echo $sanitized;
 ?>
```

The output expected should be :
    Hel lo w orld!

Thank you

Comment: What output did you get?

Comment: While JavaScript it's still the same regex - possible duplicate of [JavaScript RegEx Remove Duplicate Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780794/javascript-regex-remove-duplicate-characters)

Comment: same with the original text

Comment: @JasonMcCreary the answers there don't work like the OP wants.

Comment: Best I can do is `Helo w orld!`. There is ambiguity for the space after `w`, since it's `w  o`, why should the white space be removed altogether in the case of `w  o`, but not in the case of `o    w`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$text = 'Hell   looo   w  orlldddddd!!!!!!!!!';
$sanitized = preg_replace('/(\w|\s|.)\\1+/', '$1',$text);
 echo $sanitized;
```

Outputs:

```
Hel lo w orld!
```

**This is the best you can do with the regex in this case.**

Comment: Expected output is `Helo world!`

Comment: That is the bast he can ever get. I do not how to explain the regex to remove spaces bitween `Hel` and `lo` and not to remove them bitween `lo` and `w`

Comment: `Hell  lo` -> `Helo` can be explained with `l` being the same character after whitespace. But yes, in the end, you can't really get `Helo world!`, but you can do better than `Hel lo w orld!`

Comment: Oh, lets wait and see what he will say.. You should better provide your answer if you know how to do that..

Comment: You would have to use a dictionary and a Levenshtein Distance algorithm to match the words. The abhorrent spaces would still be a problem.

Comment: @IanAtkin Guy, you are right, but he asked for a PHP regex.

Comment: Regexes are awesome... but they ain't magic! :)

Comment: Come on, regex can do everything we want, I only want Helo World!, no double spaces/white space and characters...

Comment: @IanAtkin +1 - that what I am trying to tell - we can not make the magic, we need logic. And the left part of the work can not be explained by regexpr logic.

Comment: @BogdanBurim yes it can, if the same letter comes after whitespace, then collapse.

Comment: @HermannGolden: You're going to be disappointed.  Regexes cannot read your mind.  If you cannot define, in plain language, what the difference between the space in "hell   llooo" and the space in "loooo w" is, then you cannot expect *any* program to be able to be written to do that.

Comment: @Esailija And what if `Is PHP Perfect?` It will give `Is PHPerfect?`. Bad.

Comment: @BogdanBurim yes, but it works according to to the logic the OP wanted. Even his expected result is bad, I.E. `helo` instead of `hello`

Comment: @Esailija Just wanted to make sure you understand this. Thank you for sharing your answer. It seems usefull to me.

Comment: Sorry its my mistake to make the sample in english, 
lets say "j jjjj x kkkk      sk" I want it to be "j j x k sk"

Comment: @HermannGolden and what is the underlying logic? Why does `hel lo` become `helo`, but `j jjj` becomes `j j`?

Comment: sorry :( the result should be "hel lo w orld!" , stupid I am...

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the slash inside the regex:

```
/(\w|\s)/\1{1,}/mi
```

Comment: `/(\w|\s)/\1{1,}/mi` - Did you test it? I did. Not working!

Comment: I didn't test it, I just found typo in regex. It should have 3 slashes, and \1 can be placed only in second group.

Comment: @alex not true, it's usable even in the first one to repeat already found groups:

`echo preg_replace('/([:])\1+/', '$1', 'a:b::c');` outputs `a:b:c`