# how to remove double characters and spaces from string

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, double, character

Please let me how to remove double spaces and characters from below string.

String = `Test----$$$$19****45@@@@   Nothing`

Clean String = `Test-$19*45@ Nothing`

I have used regex `"\s+"` but it just removing the double spaces and I have tried other patterns of regex but it is too complex...  please help me.

I am using vb.net

Comment: In which language are you programming? Not all regex engines are created equally.

Comment: Here you can find anserwers [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780794/javascript-regex-remove-duplicate-characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780794/javascript-regex-remove-duplicate-characters)

Comment: I am using vb.net and dont know anything about RegEx and I am trying to learn it... if you give me an example pattern it will be great help for me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a faster alternative try:

```
        Dim text As String = "Test@@@_&aa&&&"

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(text.Length)
        Dim lastChar As Char
        For Each c As Char In text
            If c <> lastChar Then
                sb.Append(c)
                lastChar = c
            End If
        Next

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
```

Comment: Thanks I have done 10-15 performance test on different columns of a large datatable and always find string functions are faster than RegEx... It seems I have to use string functions to archive my goal in a better way. Please give me your advice. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 5):

What you'll want to do is create a backreference to any character, and then remove the following characters that match that backreference. It's usually possible using the pattern `(.)\1+`, which should be replaced with just that backreference (once). It depends on the programming language how it's exactly done.

```
Dim text As String = "Test@@@_&aa&&&"
Dim result As String = New Regex("(.)\1+").Replace(text, "$1")
```

`result` will now contain `Test@_&a&`. Alternatively, you can use a lookaround to not remove that backreference in the first place:

```
Dim text As String = "Test@@@_&aa&&&"
Dim result As String = New Regex("(?<=(.))\1+").Replace(text, "")
```

**Edit:** included examples

Comment: Thanks Patrickdev... I am using vb.net and dont know anything about RegEx and I am trying to learn it... if you give me an example pattern it will be great help for me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Ashi: I've included examples that show how to do it in VB.NET.

Comment: Thank you so much Patrickdev... But it is removing all double characters I dont want to remove double characters of the alpha. I just wanted to remove $,-,@,*,& etc. I am sorry i did not post my question correctly.

Comment: @Ashi: Just replace the `.` with `[^A-Za-z0-9]`. This is a character class that matches anything that's **not** (the `^` negates it) either an uppercase letter, lowercase letter or number. Therefore, it will remove anything else. Your pattern would then look like `([^A-Za-z0-9])\1+`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl way to substitute all multiple non word chars by only one:

```
my $String = 'Test----$$$$19****45@@@@ Nothing';
$String =~ s/(\W)\1+/$1/g;
print $String;
```

**output:**

```
Test-$19*45@ Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it would look in Java...

```
String raw = "Test----$$$$19****45@@@@ Nothing";
String cleaned = raw.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
System.out.println(raw);
System.out.println(cleaned);
```

prints

```
Test----$$$$19****45@@@@ Nothing
Test-$19*45@ Nothing
```